# Strange Foreign Key constraint in fluent mapped SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

I have a model written using FluentNhibernate and I am trying to create some test data in an in-memory SQLite database.

```
var fConfig =
                Fluently.Configure()
                        .Database(config)
                        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(exampleClass))
                        .Conventions.Add(AutoImport.Never())
                        .Conventions.Add(new SQLiteGeometryTypeConvention())
                         .Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never()))
                        .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => configuration = cfg);
```

The problem I am getting is that one of the tables is created like this in the generated sql something like this :

```
 create table myTable (
       myID  integer primary key autoincrement,
       ...{skip normal columns} 
       ForeignTable1ID INT,
       ParentID BIGINT,
       constraint FK1A2E045AFEC6908F foreign key (ForeignTable1ID) references ForeignTable1,
       constraint FK1A2E045ABB4EBD1F foreign key (ParentID) references Parent,
       constraint FKE21911CF6853D06E foreign key (myID) references Parent
)
```

I don't want that third constraint but don't know what's causing it!
The effect being that I can only create records in myTable which have valid foreign keys BUT ALSO have a myID value which exists in the Parent table. This is unnecessary, and I can't see what's causing it.

The mapping file looks like this:

```
Table("dbo.PalslagInventering");
            Id(x => x.myId).Column("myID");
            References(x => x.ForeignTable1).Column("ForeignTable1ID");
            References(x => x.Parent).Column("ParentID");

            Map(x => x.{other columns here});

HasMany(x => x.Child).KeyColumn("myID");
            HasOne(x => x.Child2).ForeignKey("MyID");

            HasMany(x => x.Child2).KeyColumn("MyID").ForeignKeyConstraintName("Child2");
            HasMany(x => x.Child3).KeyColumn("MyID").ForeignKeyConstraintName("Child3");
```

The parent table (being referenced) has a simple

```
public virtual IList<MyTable> myTableRecords { get; private set; }
```

Type of code mapped as:

```
HasMany(x => x.myTableRecords)
                .KeyColumn("myID")
                .Inverse();
```

What is causing the "foreign key" reference back to it's own myId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be:

```
HasMany(x => x.myTableRecords)
                .KeyColumn("myID")
                .Inverse();
```

Where it's the Child table (i.e. "MyTable") which has the ID "myID" and the KeyColumn should point to the Parent table (i.e. the foreign key in "MyTable").

So:

```
HasMany(x => x.myTableRecords)
                .KeyColumn("ParentID")
                .Inverse();
```

Seems to have fixed the problem. That the error was in the parent class's mapping file meant I missed it at first.